# mvc angularjs autocomplete

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete

I am trying to implement textbox autocomplete functionality in MVC angularjs. I have see examples with angucomplete method but it gets all db values in one shot. When I hit the key back again it doesnt go to MVC controller action.

Below is my code view code:

```
<div ng-controller="sampleController">
        <div ng-app="medAapp" ng-controller="sampleController">
            <div angucomplete-alt id="txtautocomplete" placeholder="Type Country name" pause="100" selected-object="AfterSelectedCoutries" local-data="countries" search-fields="Country" title-field="Country" minlength="1" input-class="form-control" match-class="highlight">

            </div>
            <div ng-show="SelectedCountries">
                Selected Country: {{SelectedCountries.Country}}
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Module code:

```
var medApp = angular.module("medApp", ['angucomplete-alt', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.pagination', 'ui.grid.selection', 'ui.grid.exporter',
    'ui.grid.grouping', 'ui.grid.expandable']);
```

Angular Controller code:

```
medApp.controller("sampleController", ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.countries = [];
    $scope.SelectedCountries = null;

    $scope.AfterSelectedCoutries = function (selected) {
        if (selected) {
            $scope.SelectedCountries = selected.originalObject;
        }
    }

    $http.get("/Home/GetCountry").then(function (d) {
        $scope.countries = d.data;
    }, function (error) {
        alert('Failed');
    })

}])
```

MVC Controller code:

```
public JsonResult Getcountry()
        {
            List<Item> listcountry = new List<Item>()
            {
                new Item()
                {
                    Id=1,
                    Name= "Crocin"
                },
                 new Item()
                {
                    Id=2,
                    Name= "Bruffen"
                }
            };
            return Json(listcountry, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

My question is GetCountry method should have a parameter to get the required records but in none of the samples it does.

Any suggestions??

Thanks

Comment: i dont understand the question please explain

Comment: @IbraHimM.Nada .... I am trying to implement the autocomplete functionality for a textbox is .NET MVC using angularJS angucomplete library. If I type a name like 'a' it should return me all the countries containing 'a' in them like 'USA', 'India', 'Pakistan' from database. Right now I have ignored database code. Hope its clear.

Comment: The controller should have an argument Called for example "keyWord" then you retrun ......

 return Json(listcountry.where(x=>x.NameTostring().Contains(keyWord)), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Comment: add the keyword in your angular Request as well 
and for best results you should Ignore case sensitive Chars

Comment: @IbraHimM.Nada ..that's my question... if I add a parameter in my C# controller method then what changes I need to do in angular code.

Comment: $http.get("/Home/GetCountry?keyWord="+<<theTextBoxValue>>+"").then(function (d)

Comment: @IbraHimM.Nada ... Thank for your reponse. I tried your code. It dint work. It doesnt hit the break point itself

$http.get("/Home/GetCountry?keyWord="+ theTextBoxValue‌).then(function (d) {
        $scope.countries = d.data;
    }, function (error) {
        alert('Failed');
    })
 
In the C# controller:

public JsonResult Getcountry(string theTextBoxValue)
{
///Other code here..
}

Comment: "public JsonResult Getcountry(string theTextBoxValue)" 
change it to 
"public JsonResult Getcountry(string keyWord)"

Comment: @IbraHimM.Nada ..that still dint work!!